# how to set a cool down on a button in sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let positionInScene = touch!.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)

            if let name = touchedNode.name {
                if name == "jumpbutton" {
                    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
                    let boost = SKAction.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 160.0), duration: 0.1)
                            let action = SKAction.group([boost, wait])
                    player!.run(action)
                    
                    print("jumpbutton")
                }
```

Here is my code where I tried to set a cool down of 3 seconds before the jump button could be pressed again. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works is creating a flag to determine whether pressing the jump button allows us to jump or it does not allow us to jump (i.e it is in cool down).
For this you create a variable called `isReady` near the top of the class and set it to true.

When it comes to the touches, we want to check whether the node we are touching is the jump button (`touchedNode.name == "jump button"`), and whether the button is ready (`isReady == true`). If both equate to true we can continue on. We first set the flag `isReady = false`, this is so we can not immediately run this section of code again (think of someone rapidly pressing the jump button).

Next part is creating the boost and running it.

Then finally, we create a wait action with a duration of 3 seconds. We run this wait action, then on completion we set the flag back to true (`isReady = true`).

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  var isReady = true

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    let positionInScene = touch!.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)

    if touchedNode.name == "jumpbutton" && isReady == true {
     
            isReady = false
      
            let boost = SKAction.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 160.0), duration: 0.1)
            player!.run(boost)
        
            print("jumpbutton")
      
            let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
            run(wait) { [self] in
              isReady = true
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much John L you have answered my questions before if I remember correctly. It works but I don't really know how, nevertheless thank you.

Comment: Ok. You will eventually understand it. There will come a time where you will need to adjust it, at first it will be difficult, but persevere, and do not give up! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply implement with actions like you were inclined to do:

```
// Disable button
let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: coolDownTime)
run(waitAction) { [weak self] in
  // Enable button
}
```

To expand on this answer I would like to propose the creation of a component, so you don't need to deal with every button press on your GameScene.

First create your button on the file SKButton.swift:

import SpriteKit

```
class SKButton: SKSpriteNode {
    
    var coolDownTime: TimeInterval = 2.0
    var isReady: Bool = true
    private var originalColor: UIColor = .red
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if isReady {
            print("This button was touched")
            originalColor = color
            color = .gray
            isReady = false
            let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: coolDownTime)
            run(waitAction) { [weak self] in
                self?.isReady = true
                self?.color = self?.originalColor ?? .blue
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is an example of it working in my GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    
  
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        
        let myButton = SKButton()
        myButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        myButton.color = .red
        myButton.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
        myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        addChild(myButton)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. What do you mean by enable my button in your first response after "weak self in".

Comment: It could be an if statement like I used in the example or it could be the interactions it self like this: isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: Sorry Im still having difficulty implementing the cool down on it. If you have the time would you be able to write it out as I honestly have tried a few times but it still does not work. Thank you.

Comment: If you still having problems with this I will share an example [repo](https://github.com/GiovanniLuigi/SKButtonExample) with the code above

Comment: Nope, all good John L answered my question.